# Javascript / css not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm testing my site on Internet Explorer via browser testing site(e.g. Lambda Test) - and it's not working at all. Nothing happens, no movement.  What's going on here and how do I fix this?  I've tested this on both IE 11 and IE 9.

From this article: [How to enable JavaScript in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135465/how-to-enable-javascript-in-windows#:%7E:text=Internet%20Explorer,-To%20allow%20all&text=On%20the%20%22Security%22%20tab%2C,Scripting%20in%20the%20Scripting%20section.&text=Click%20the%20Refresh%20button%20to%20refresh%20the%20page%20and%20run%20scripts)

It looks like sometimes you have to manually enable javascript, and I'm assuming that sites like lambda test have this enabled already. I use Mac,  so I can't actually use IE.

Update - CSS:

```
 img
{
  display:none;
  height: 400px;
}


 img.invisible
{
  visibility: hidden;
}

img.show
{
  display:inline;
}

img.anim1
{
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
}

 img.anim2
{
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
}

img.anim3
{
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
}


.fadeIn
{
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeIn 
{
 0% {opacity: 0;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}


@-ms-keyframes fadeIn 
{
 0% {opacity: 0;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeOut
{
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeOut 
{
 0% {opacity: 1;}
 100% {opacity: 0; display:none;}
}
```

```
    
    <section class="conA">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="heroText">
         <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <div id="text"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="images"></div>
    </div>
    </section>
    
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var _CONTENT = [ "lorem ipsum", "example sentence"
    , "example 2", "example 3" ];
    
    
    var IMAGE_URLS = ['img/image2.png', 'img/image1.png', 'img/image3.png', 'img/image1.png','img/image2.png','img/image3.png', 'img/image4.png','img/image5.png','img/image6.png','https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a235706e3d81b614acaec3368edfea4b?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG','https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxeUf.jpg?s=96&g=1','https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xczZ.jpg?s=96&g=1'];
    
    var IMAGES = IMAGE_URLS.map((url, index) =>
    {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.setAttribute('src', url);
      img.classList.add('anim'+((index%3)+1));
      img.classList.add('fadeOut');
      document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
      return img;
    });
    
    var _PART = 0;
    
    var _PART_INDEX = 0;
    
    var _INTERVAL_VAL;
    
    var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");
    
    function Type() { 
      var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
      _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
      _PART_INDEX++;
    
      if(text === _CONTENT[_PART]) {
    
      let imgIndexBase = _PART*3;
        IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('fadeOut');
        IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.remove('fadeOut');
        IMAGES[imgIndexBase+2].classList.remove('fadeOut');
        setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeIn','show'); }, 0);
        setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeOut'); }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('fadeOut','show'); }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.add('fadeIn','show'); }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.add('fadeOut'); }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase+1].classList.remove('fadeOut','show'); }, 7000);
        setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase+2].classList.add('fadeIn','show'); }, 7000);
        setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase+2].classList.add('fadeOut'); }, 9000);
        setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase+2].classList.remove('fadeOut','show'); }, 10000);
      
    
    
    
        clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
        setTimeout(function() {
          _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Delete, 50);
        }, 11000);
    
      }
    }
    
    
    
        function Delete() {
      var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
      _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
      _PART_INDEX--;
    
      // If sentence has been deleted then start to display the next sentence
      if(text === '') {
     
    
    
        clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
    
        // If last sentence then display the first one, else move to the next
        if(_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
          _PART = 0;
        else
          _PART++;
        _PART_INDEX = 0;
    
        // Start to display the next sentence after some time
        setTimeout(function() {
          _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
        }, 500);
      }
    }
    
    _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
    
    </script>
```

Comment: It's probably the `let` keyword as that's unsupported in any form of IE. Do check the console for any errors. But please let's just leave IE behind, even IE11 is 7 years old - ancient history in browser terms, and virtually no-one uses it (MS have moved to Edge since 2015). As for IE9, that's even more ancient history - there may be a few people still using IE11 but surely not IE9!

Comment: Note that, assuming `let` is indeed the issue and you really have to make this work on IE, then simply replacing the `let` with `var` should be OK here.

Comment: IE does not support arrow functions.

Comment: oh yes, I missed the arrow function - that definitely won't work in IE

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the arrow function, but still having trouble here - text animation is working, but image animation isn't working at all.   Are there things other than arrow function that need to be fixed?

Comment: I think you should also provide the css code because you use some classes like `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` and so on on the images. We don't know if the class properties are compatible with IE. The text animation has nothing to do with the classes but the image animation is related with the classes. So with the css code we can have a better understanding of the issue and see how to help.

Comment: Ah - thanks for pointing that out. Updated the post with CSS

Comment: Yes - thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the es6 syntax issue, I think you have corrected according to the comments and the answer ealier. There's another issue you should fix in your code: [IE 11 doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility) multiple arguments for `add()` & `remove()` in `classList`. So you can't use code like

```
setTimeout(function() { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeIn','show'); }, 0);
```

You need to change it to

```
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeIn'); }, 0);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('show'); }, 0);
```

Also it's the same for the other `classList.add()` & `classList.remove()` with multiple arguments in your code.

So the edited part of your code snippet is like below:

```
//edit arrow function

var IMAGES = IMAGE_URLS.map(function (url, index) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', url);
    img.classList.add('anim' + (index % 3 + 1));
    img.classList.add('fadeOut');
    document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
    return img;
});
```

```
//edit classList in function Type()

let imgIndexBase = _PART * 3;
IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('fadeOut');
IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.remove('fadeOut');
IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 2].classList.remove('fadeOut');
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeIn'); }, 0);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('show'); }, 0);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.add('fadeOut'); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('fadeOut'); }, 3000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase].classList.remove('show'); }, 3000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.add('fadeIn'); }, 3000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.add('show'); }, 3000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.add('fadeOut'); }, 5000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.remove('fadeOut'); }, 7000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 1].classList.remove('show'); }, 7000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 2].classList.add('fadeIn'); }, 7000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 2].classList.add('show'); }, 7000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 2].classList.add('fadeOut'); }, 9000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 2].classList.remove('fadeOut'); }, 10000);
setTimeout(function () { IMAGES[imgIndexBase + 2].classList.remove('show'); }, 10000);
```

Result in IE 11:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You try to use lambda functions and map ES6 function which are both not supported by IE. If you use jQuery then you can use jQuery's equivalent of ES6 map function:

```
var mappedArray = $.map(realArray, function(val, i ) {
  // Do something
});
```

You should also use var instead of let and const keywords which are not supported by IE as well.

Replace your array function

```
IMAGE_URLS.map((url, index) => {}
```

with:

```
jQuery.map(IMAGE_URLS, function (url, index)
{
  //mapping code here
}
```

Comment: Sorry would you mind being specific about what exactly I should write?  I'm new and frankly have no idea what you're saying about lambda functions and ES6 map.

Comment: Lambda is also known as arrow functions () => {}. You should use traditional function() {} syntax which I denoted above. I also gave you an example how to use jQeury mapping function.

Comment: no need whatsoever for jQuery here - just use regular JS `map` (as in the OP) but replace the arrow function with a regular `function` expression. Since `this` isn't used inside it will make no difference to the result here.

Comment: using jQuery mapping function did enable text animation (thanks) - I have 2 sets of animation here though, text and IMAGE animation. Image animation isn't working at all - how to fix this?

Comment: @lukbrt are there things other than the array function that I need to change?

Comment: Maybe you might need to add animations atrributes with -ms prefixes, e.g.: -ms-animation, @-ms-keyframes

Comment: @lukbrt hey thanks but that didn't work, either. are there other things i can try?