# Adjusting spacing between Flexbox items in IE while using Grid Layout for other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, flexbox, grid-layout

Given that IE doesn't fully support Grid Layout, I'm using Flexbox for Internet Explorer only, and using Grid Layout for other browsers.

Is there a way to add margin/padding to flex items on IE only, and have this not affect Grid Layout items?

Right now, there's no space between flexbox items - I know normally you'd add margin or padding to  ".grid article", but that doesn't work in this case b/c that'd add margin or padding to Grid items, too (in Grid Layout in Chrome, for example).

```
.grid {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start; 
  margin-top: -20px;

} 


.grid article {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
}


.grid a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;

}



@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 70px;
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
  } 
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px) {
  .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 40px;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  } 

  }    
   <div class="grid> 

   <article> 
    <a href="#">
   <div>Sample content goes here</div> 
    </a>
  </article> 

   <article> 
    <a href="#">
   <div>Sample content goes here</div> 
    </a>
  </article> 

   <article> 
    <a href="#">
   <div>Sample content goes here</div> 
    </a>
  </article> 

   <article> 
    <a href="#">
   <div>Sample content goes here</div> 
    </a>
  </article> 

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes - thank you!  If you're familiar with IE,  would you mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287560/javascript-codes-not-working-in-internet-explorer   I fixed lambda function and tried -ms-keyframes but image animation still not working

Comment: I post an answer in it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287560/javascript-codes-not-working-in-internet-explorer/64386329#64386329. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use the following methods to solve this issue:

**Method 1:** You can add [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to the `.grid` to allow each element in IE to maintain spacing. It is used to set or retrieve the alignment of the elastic box elements in the main axis (horizontal axis) direction:

```
.grid {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: start;
    margin-top: -20px;
    justify-content: space-between; /*add this line*/
}
```

**Method 2:** You can use **media queries** to target IE in CSS like below, then the style in the media queries will only apply on IE 11 and the style outside will apply on all the browsers:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
/* IE10+ CSS */
    .grid article {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
        margin-right: 225px;
    }
}

.grid article {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yu Zhou   would you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302867/adjusting-spacing-between-flexbox-items-in-ie-while-using-grid-layout-for-other    it's an IE issue